# woocoomerce bulk product variant update with batch processing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, batch-processing, product-variations

I want to make update multiple product variants with batch processing
with the woocommerce standard functions. I learned that there is a REST API endpoint https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-product-variations that is solving my issue but I am looking for a function/method instead of an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a custom form handler for processing your batch.
- Put handler code in custom function or function.php file in theme
- You can copy the API endpoint code and put it in your form handler code.

This way, when the batch processing starts, your custom form handler will kick in and execute the code copied from end point.

You might need to tweak that end point code slightly in case if any variable name needs to be changed.